# combine find statements

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, find

How can i combine both of the below commands? I want to get a single file with the owner and the size of the files

```
find /test -type f -size +$(df -k /test| awk 'NR == 3 { printf "%d", 
$1/4 }') -exec du -sh {} +


find /test -type f -size +$(df -k /test | awk 'NR == 3 { printf "%d", 
$1/4 }') -exec stat -c '%U' {} +
```

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: should list size of the files and owner

Comment: ... and the filename, corresponding with the `du` command? Just curious if the size & filename should come first, or the owner

Comment: yes. order should really matter.

Comment: file owner size

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options, where I've pruned out the bulk of your `find` statement so that it focuses on the different ways to combine them:

1. combine the `find` statements into a "find-shell":

   ```
   find ... -exec sh -c 'printf "%s - %s - %s\n" "$1" "$(stat -c %U "$1")" "$(du -sh "$1")"' find-sh {} \;
   ```

This passes the files one at a time into the shell command, which combines the `stat` and `du` commands into a formatted `printf` statement. This second option passes multiple files at a time to the `stat` command.

2. combine the functionality with `stat`:

   ```
   find ... -exec stat -c '%n %U %s' {} +
   ```

The `stat` option prints the size in bytes, which is slightly different from the `du -h` format.

---

A third option exists, if you have GNU find available, for its `-printf` extension:

```
find ... -printf '%p %u %s\n'
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. trying to include one more find here, Can you advice on how I can do that? find ..... -exec printf "%s\n" "$(awk -F '=' '/ID/ { print $2}' "$1")"' find-sh {} \; Basically this is grepping for ID from the same file which is in the form ID=0000

Comment: The comment formatting makes it hard to interpret what's going on; I'd suggest a new question that explains exactly what you're going for and where you are now.

Comment: I did post a new question . Here is the link  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480204/error-while-executing-shell-script?noredirect=1#comment878434_480204